# opencv + openframeworks + codeblocks + win7

Tags: opencv, codeblocks, openframeworks

I am a new user of opencv, trying to get this combination working, and need some help.

I have these versions: openframeworks=71, codeblocks+mingw=10.05, opencv=2.4.2, and am on win7.

In the OF installation, I found some files addons/ofxOpenCv/.../*231.a - does this mean that it supports opencv-2.3.1 only ?

Also, is there any procedure for integrating the two - e.g. any environment variables to set before I run the example in examples/addons/opencvExample?

Has anybody tried this combination of softwares? If so, can you guide me - where to find the packages, how to install and run?

If needed, I can move to a previous version of opencv, just to get the combination working.

Answer (score 1):

I should be able to use newer libraries. I've just tested with openFrameworks 007(0), Code::Blocks+MingW and OpenCV 2.4.2, but on Win XP SP3. I changed the paths in the project's linker options to point to OpenCV 2.4.2 libraries instead. In the .cbp xml, that would be changing

```
<Add option="../../../addons/ofxOpenCv/libs/opencv/lib/win_cv/libopencv_calib220.a" />
...etc.
```

to something like

```
<Add option="C:\OpenCV\lib\opencv_calib3d242d.lib" />
...etc.
```

for a quick test. On my Windows machine I have OpenCV installed straight onto C:, but I imagine making of copy of the headers and libraries inside openframeworks and using relative paths would be cleaner for more 'future proof' ( so I ca keep older version of OF still working with all apps, although I might install a newer version of OpenCV in the future).

You mentioned integration and I do warmly recommend [Kyle McDonalds's ofxCv](https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv) addon, which among many other nice wrapper functionalities like `toOf()` and `toCv()` which makes it easy to convert between `ofImage` and `cv::Mat` types. I've used this addon successfully before (albeit on OSX, and with a different highui lib since I needed to access an IP Camera, but I imagine once linking is setup properly in the project, everything should also be fine on Windows).